# Auto-accepted a job offer, then spamming from my account

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, spam

I got a message today with a job offer, but I didn't read it until a couple of hours later.

Somehow, the interview was automatically accepted and somebody/something started spamming messages from my account with the text "Notification" in it.

How do I stop the spam?

Comment: Have you tried changing your password?

Comment: It's not e-mail, these are SO messages from my account to the person who sent me the offer.

Comment: Yeah, we saw this. My first guess was that you have some sort of email auto-responder set up which has gone rogue. Is that possible?

Comment: @GB s/email password/SO password/

Comment: I didn't get any e-mail from SO or from that person, only the message on SO jobs

Comment: There is an automatic notification from my .tk domain, when somebody sends a mail for the first time. But I didn't get any e-mail on that address (and I just checked, the forwarding is active) and this should only happen once per sender e-mail address.

Comment: Upon further inspection the messages seem to be "undeliverable" notifications. The original message from the employer didn't manage to reach your inbox, and the mail provider is sending a ton of replies to our mail server. I'll see what I can do about putting a temporary ban on that address

Comment: I will also change my email address in the profile. I disabled the captcha but it's not enough, it seems.

Answer (score 27):

It seems like your mail provider was accidentally abusing our reply-by-email feature.

The original email notifying you of the employer's message bounced. (I don't know why.) The mail server decided to reply with not one, not two, but - count'em - *forty-five* automated "undeliverable message" notifications. Our mail system is designed so that email replies conveniently go into the chain of messages, so those 45 messages ended up in the employer's inbox.

I've blocked the mail provider's automated email address from sending replies. (Replies from your actual email should still be OK.)

Obviously I can't talk about personal information like specific email addresses or mail providers in public, so if you'd like to discuss specifics please get in touch with us privately at team@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I don't think the problem is solved, I see a lot of new messages in the thread (still spamming 9 hours after your answer)

Comment: I'll look into it as soon as I get to the office. :)

Comment: It looks like the undeliverable email changes its `from` address periodically. Annoying! I've changed the list of banned addresses to be a regular expression (previously it was just looking for exact matches) so any addresses matching the apparent pattern should now be blocked. I also suggest that you complain to your email provider ;)

Comment: The email provider is actually GMail, the other address is a redirect I can't just turn off. But it never happened before, so I think there is some other problem like a ping-pong between ever-changing e-mail addresses. Are you sure you aren't sending messages from different addresses too? I can only see the whitelist (but I can't whitelist regex), and it looks like you keep replying to the undeliverable message...